# NativeScript - page-router-outlet doesn't export outlet property?

Tags: angular, animation, routes, nativescript, nativescript-angular

i must perform the navigation into some section of the app from a floating bar. The bar have 3 button, and on the click of one button i must navigate to the respective page.

I made this by using a page-router-outlet, but now the customer want an animation on the leaving and on the appearing page.

When a button is clicked, the page that i'm leaving must slideDown of 100px and the new page must slideUp of 100px.

For doing this, i founded this angular example - https://stackblitz.com/angular/pylgondypnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html - but i think it should be not an acceptable solution.

I'm trying to mix something like this:
`[nsRouterLink]="paths[0]" nsRouterLinkActive="selected" pageTransition="slideDown" clearHistory="true"`
with an animation loaded from the destination page, at the onload.

This solution is still not working very well.

Which could be the correct way to do two different animations on the leaving and on the appearing page?

Thank you

Comment: You must implement native animation between Pages (routes). slideDown is not a valid value, it should be **slideTop** or **slideBottom**, for complete list of built-in transitions refer the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_ui_frame_.navigationtransition#name).

Comment: Hi, the problem is that i haven't found a way to do it with page-router-outlet. Is there a way to do it, or i must switch to router-outlet?
P.s. Yes, then i switched from slideDown to slideBottom, i wasn't able to find the list of acceptable value

Comment: The list of values can be found in the Frame / Navigation Transition docs. I guess the router link setup already supports page transition parameter. If you have issues, please share a Playground sample of your try.